# Duplicate a model @Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I'm working on a family practitioner model, my goal is to model the population of a city and all of the family practitioners in that given city by taking into account the distribution of the treatment time and the arrival schedule of patients etc... I've started with a basic model with two practitioners and a small population.

[Basic Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwH7k.png)

Now if im going to model all of the 10k practitioners by duplicating the same blocks its gonna be like undoable, the other solution is to add more units in the resourcepool which does not model the real situation because basicly every family practitioner have his own queue and increasing the resourcepool is like modelling 'n' family practitioner in the same clinic with the same shared queue of patients.  Is there any other solution? (first time using anylogic so im basicly a newbie)
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your model architecture fundamentally. Practitioners become a custom agent type, you create a population of them and provide a flow chart in that agent type. Then, you can have 10k of them each with their own flow chart.

Strongly recommend you do all the tutorials in the help first to get a better understanding of the capabilities of AnyLogic. Having some blocks on Main is really just 0.1% of what the tool is capable of :)

Comment: Thank you, ill start doing the tutorials.
Would you further explain your idea please?

Comment: Hi @WissemAboub, happy to help but StackOverflow is not the place to "further explain an idea", this is a place for specific questions and specific answers. If you seek more general explanations and support, the LinkedIn forum is the better place. See here for an intro for AnyLogic beginners: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/11/12/an-introduction-to-the-anylogic-community . And here for some tips how to best leverage SOF: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Thank you so much you are a life saver i was a bit lost, i will try to better formulate my problem and post it on linkedin forum. thanks again